# Error in yml gitlab CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab

I have this in `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
build_api:
 stage: build
 script:
  - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
  - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
only:
 ---->  variables:  <----- Error
    - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == /\[pipeline\]|(merge)/i      
except:
  - master
```

In CI Lint in gitlab say `*Error* : jobs:build_api:only variables invalid expression syntax`

**why its the reason ?**

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this page: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#variables-expressions

It seems you have to use `=~` when matching patterns.
Try

```
- $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[pipeline\]|(merge)/i
```

Double equals `==` only accepts strings, null, or variables.

Comment: but still this doesn't works, see the issue here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/55599 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/50137

@andreas-volkmann

Comment: I've found an approach due to my silly mistakes, see here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/618#note_283744285 @alex-montoya